# View in MYSQL with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have 3 tables in mysql

```
table 1
date        name   total recieve
2013-05-09  "aa"    20    15
2013-05-09  "bb"    10    17

table 2
name    tree
"bb"     "a1"
"aa"     "a2"

table 3
date          tree      users
2013-05-09   "a1SI"      19
2013-05-09   "a1NO"      24
2013-05-09   "a2SI"      39
2013-05-09   "a2NO"      22
```

I need a view with the tree tables

this is the view that i need:

```
date         name   tree   total    recieve    userSI    userNO  
2013-05-09   "aa"   "a2"    20        15        39         22
2013-05-09   "bb"   "a1"    10        17        19         24
```

I have half of the query

```
SELECT t1.`date` , t1.`name` , t2.`tree` , t1.`total` , t1.`recieve`,
FROM  `table1` t1
INNER JOIN  `table2` t2 ON t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
ORDER BY  `t1`.`date` DESC
```

But i don't know how do the view with the three tables and the other problems is the records of the tree because i have tree "a1" and "a1Si" and "a2NO"  and in the view i need relate the 3 columns

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use the following which JOINS `table3` on the `t2.tree` and the left two characters of the `t3.tree`:

```
SELECT t1.`date` , t1.`name` , t2.`tree` , t1.`total` , t1.`recieve`,
  max(case when right(t3.tree, 2) = 'SI' then t3.users end) usersSI,
  max(case when right(t3.tree, 2) = 'NO' then t3.users end) usersNO
FROM  `table1` t1
INNER JOIN  `table2` t2 
  ON t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
INNER JOIN `table3` t3
  on t2.tree = left(t3.tree, 2)
group by t1.`date` , t1.`name` , t2.`tree` , t1.`total` , t1.`recieve`
ORDER BY  `t1`.`date` DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08bb0/5).

This could also be done using multiple JOINs on `table3`:

```
SELECT t1.`date` , t1.`name` , t2.`tree` , t1.`total` , t1.`recieve`,
  t3SI.users usersSI,
  t3NO.users usersNO
FROM  `table1` t1
INNER JOIN  `table2` t2 
  ON t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
LEFT JOIN `table3` t3SI
  on t2.tree = left(t3SI.tree, 2)
  and right(t3SI.tree, 2) = 'SI'
LEFT JOIN `table3` t3NO
  on t2.tree = left(t3NO.tree, 2)
  and right(t3NO.tree, 2) = 'NO'
ORDER BY  `t1`.`date` DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08bb0/6). You will notice that I altered the last two joins to use a `LEFT JOIN` in the event a tree does not exist that matches the `SI` or `NO`, then you will return data. If you know that you will have matching data, then you can use an INNER JOIN.

If you have tree names that are longer, then you could implement the LIKE clause in the JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.`date` , t1.`name` , t2.`tree` , t1.`total` , t1.`recieve`,
  t3SI.users usersSI,
  t3NO.users usersNO
FROM  `table1` t1
INNER JOIN  `table2` t2 
  ON t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
LEFT JOIN `table3` t3SI
  on t3SI.tree like concat(t2.tree, '%')
  and right(t3SI.tree, 2) = 'SI'
LEFT JOIN `table3` t3NO
  on t3NO.tree like concat(t2.tree, '%')
  and right(t3NO.tree, 2) = 'NO'
ORDER BY  `t1`.`date` DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08bb0/8)

Comment: But when i do max(case when right(t3.tree, 2) = 'SI' then t3.users end) usersSI,
  max(case when right(t3.tree, 2) = 'NO' then t3.users end) usersNO.  Only show me one record and i have 80 records with userSI and userNO

Comment: @BenitoCamelas See my edit, you can also use multiple joins to get the results.

Comment: Ohh the proble is when you do left(t3SI.tree, 2)  if a have a tree with aname with 5 letters, not working

Comment: @BenitoCamelas You should include all necessary details in your original post.  You could also try to use the LIKE clause in the JOIN.

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry for the accidental down-vote (and subsequent strange edit to unlock it).  I must have clicked wildly without realizing it. Now up-voted instead!

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join with the third table two times as below:

```
    SELECT t1.'date' , t1.'name' , t2.'tree' , t1.'total' , t1.'recieve',
      t31.users usersSI,
      t32.users usersNO
    FROM  'table1' t1
    INNER JOIN  'table2' t2 
      ON t1.'name' = t2.'name' 
    INNER JOIN 'table3' t31
      on t2.tree = left(t31.tree, 2) AND right(t31.tree, 2) = 'SI'
    INNER JOIN 'table3' t32
      on t2.tree = left(t32.tree, 2) AND right(t32.tree, 2) = 'NO'
    group by t1.'date' , t1.'name' , t2.'tree' , t1.'total' , t1.'recieve'
    ORDER BY  't1'.'date' DESC;
```